# Select drop-down values keep growing instead of being replaced (via AngularJS controller)

Tags: angularjs

My HTML View (coupled to AngularJS controller) is not updating as expected based on a changing @$scope.___ value in the controller.

***What is supposed to happen:***

1. User selects a Category from drop down menu.
2. Beneath that, an Items drop down menu appears, showing items from the chosen Category.
3. If the user changes the Category in the first menu, the Items menu options change to show only Items within the newly selected Category.

***What actually happens, much to my chagrin:***

Instead of repopulating the Items dropdown menu when the user changes Category, the items from the NEW Category are APPENDED to the available Items in the dropdown menu.  So if the user changes Category 5 times, the list of Items grows very long indeed, and includes Items from all 5 Categories.

I don't get it.

Here's my relevant html:

```
<select
    ng-model='predicate.categoryId'
    <!-- The important line -->
    ng-change='controller.populateItemsByCategory()'
    ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories | orderBy:'name'">
</select>
<select
    ng-model='predicate.itemId'
    ng-change='controller.itemSelected()'
    ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in categoryItems track by item.id">
</select>
```

And my pertinent CoffeeScript + Lodash, housed in my Controller instance:

```
@$scope.categoryItems = [] 

populateItemsByCategory: =>

  // Make sure scope.categoryItems is EMPTY...
  // but the items are still showing in the select dropdown in the view. :-S
  @$scope.categoryItems.length = 0

  // Logging it gives me an empty array, which is good.
  console.log(@$scope.categoryItems)

  // We make our call to the back end (via an internal Rails API)...
  @Items.index
    category_id: @$scope.predicate.categoryId
  .$promise
  .then (items) =>
    @$scope.categoryItems = items

    // This log gives me the correct array of items, as expected.
    // But it's not reflected in the View.  What gives?
    console.log(@$scope.categoryItems)
```

Comment: When you change your category and call `populateItemsByCategory`, you have to first empty the second dropdown and then you have to add the options to it

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that's exactly what I am doing.